# Invoke Javascript OnChange Event

Tags: c#, onchange, invoke, mshtml

I am stuck for the first time in a while.
These days I use HtmlAgilityPack for web scraping info but for dynamic data I must use a browser control first.
I have failed on IE and Visual Studios Webbrowser control to trigger an OnChange Javascript code so I must ask for help.

The link is here:
http://www.abetterstay.com/propertydetail.aspx?cin=10/30/2012&cout=11/01/2012&c=1989

I need to trigger: `onchange="OnSelectRoomChange(this);"`

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderHeader$Booking1$selectBedrooms" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderHeader_Booking1_selectBedrooms" class="select_bedrooms" onchange="OnSelectRoomChange(this);">
    <option selected="selected" value="5238">1 bedroom/2 bathroom gulf front view</option>
    <option value="5239">2 bedroom/2 bathroom gulf front view</option>
    <option value="5240">3 bedroom/3 bathroom gulf front view</option>
</select>
```

Someone please tell me what needs to be done..
All my attempts fail. I can change the selected value but of course nothing triggers.

This was a fail...

```
HTMLWindow2 iHtmlWindow2 = (HTMLWindow2)doc.Script;
iHtmlWindow2.execScript("OnSelectRoomChange(this);", "javascript");
```

Comment: Well, don't know what should exactly happen, but checking the debugger the method is actually executed. Try to insert some breakpoints and check yourself.